# enabled IPv6 but [::1] is not working

Tags: ipv6, internet-explorer-7

Windows XP with IE 7

http://localhost works.
http://127.0.0.1 works.
http://[machinename] works.
http://[::1] does not work.

A separate W2K3 machine works with all four addresses.

I did the same IPv6 installation on both machines (Network properties>Install IPv6)

Answer (score 1):

Check the bindings is IIS or which ever web server you are using locally.  Otherwise the port isn't going to be listened to.

If you're using IIS 5.1, it doesn't support IPv6, so it won't bind to the IPv6 addresses and ports.  MS added the support in 6.0.

Comment: how do you do that?  My XP has IIS 5.1

Comment: Right click the site and go to Properties. Under the Web Site tab, the IP Address field will show the bindings.  Under the Advanced options you can bind it to specific IP addresses.  5.1 may not support IPv6 though.

Comment: 5.1 doesn't support IPv6.  They added the support in 6.0

Comment: since 5.1 doesn't support IPv6, I tried to view the website that is on my W2K3 server using its' IPv6 address (since it's installed on my XP machine).  When I put in the address, http://[ab80::5cde:...etc], I get "Windows cannot find http://...  Check the spelling and try again.  I know the address is valid because it worked on another W2K3 machine in the domain.

Comment: Does your hardware support IPv6 between the W2K3 server and the XP machine?  Try pinging it through IPv6, you'll need to make sure the version of the ping utility supports IPv6 also.  The modern Windows versions have additional information in the help command that reference IPv6, the older version will not, and will not support IPv6.